# Calling runas in VBS broken by policy?

Tags: vbscript, wsh, runas

I have been calling runas from VBScript using:

```
wshShell.Run("runas /user:... cscript another.vbs") 
WScript.Sleep 500 'wait for launch
wshShell.AppActivate(pathtorunasexe) 'take focus
wshShell.SendKeys pass & VBCRLF
```

I have been doing this for years with no problems. I use this to torture test an application by running a script with many different credentials.

However, after updating last night this has stopped working. Version now reads Windows 10 Enterprise Build 15063.

The point-of-failure is SendKeys. The Windows exits immediately. If I add /netonly it works. The script called by runas runs as the user as expected. However this raises a new issue. Multiple runas calls do not work. The first call works but any secondary calls fail. The cmd windows just close.

So clearly something has changed. It seems like maybe MS has changed something to prevent this sort of thing. Does anyone know what it could be and how I can fix this?

More generally, how can I launch 100 VBScripts using a list of identities and credentials? I need to do this for torture testing my software product.

Comment: I was able to test this and it worked fine. I have a Win10 Home Build 15063.674.

Comment: It feels like some kind of security policy because /netonly works for one call and not others so it doesn't surprise me too much that it worked for you.

Comment: Have you  tried to run the key listener and key sender under the same user?  That is, using the `runas` to start the wapper/sendkeys script, that will launch (without `runas`) the process waiting the input and then send the input.